# How to bridge connections?

Tags: 10.10, connection, share, tether

I'm looking for a way to bridge my connection like the way it's done in Windows.
example
If I have an Internet connection via wifi and want to share that connection to my xbox via Ethernet
or vice versa
also I some times tether off my phone and want to share that connection via Ethernet is there a simple way to do this?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 32bit laptop anymore info needed just ask.

Answer (score 1):

edit the ipv4 connection settings for your ethernet connection to your xbox to be "Shared to other computers" instead of "Automatic DHCP", not sure but you may need a "crossover cable" or "crossover adapter" poof your done, i think some network adapters dont require crossover cables or maybe i mixed up my cables in the past :-)

any router in the middle of xbox and laptop is handy, such as a hub or switch, this will remove the need for a crossover cable.  i have an old dsl modem (no longer used as a modem) aka a router, which i turned off "DHCP" and "NAT" options (for most devices make a connection to device with a static IP of something like 192.168.0.9 with subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 and open a web browser to goto web page http://192.168.0.1 to see settings, your device may use different IP's to configure, turn off DHCP on device and its done) now your laptop is a wifi hotspot

if the computers connection to the router is set to "Shared to other computer" then anything connecting to the router will share whatever internet connection the laptop has.  This type of connection will put everything behind a layer of NAT and not be a true bridge, your xbox wont care, i know - ive done it

p.s. the daring could splice an ethernet cable and turn it into a crossover, info is on google if you trust random web pages, not recommended

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a GUI for bridge-utils to create bridges graphically. You can download it:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bridger/files/netbridge_3.1-2_deb.tar.gz/download